# image not getting parsed in php from FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I have set up my code to pass formdata via Ajax to my php file.  My code works until I actually select an image and then I get a parsing error in my php file.  I get an undefined index error.  I have a form named "AddItemForm".  My image input line looks like this:

```
 <input type="file" id="_ni_image_in" onchange="readURL(this);" name="ni_image" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

My javascript/ajax code looks like this which gets called when submit button is selected on form:

```
function AddItem(){
var form = document.forms["AddItemForm"];
var name = document.forms["AddItemForm"]["ni_name"].value;
var tag = document.forms["AddItemForm"]["ni_tag"].value;
var description = document.forms["AddItemForm"]["ni_description"].value;
var weight = document.forms["AddItemForm"]["ni_weight"].value;
var date = document.forms["AddItemForm"]["ni__date"].value;
var color = document.forms["AddItemForm"]["ni_color"].value;
var itag2 = document.forms["AddItemForm"]["ni_tag2"].value;
var itag3 = document.forms["addcowform"]["ni_tag3"].value;
var useremail= "<?php echo $_SESSION['UserEmail']; ?>";

var itemdata = new FormData();

    var filedata = document.getElementById("_nc_image_in").files[0];
    itemdata.append('Item_Image', filedata);

itemdata.append('Name', name);
itemdata.append('Tag_Num', tag);
itemdata.append('Description', description);
itemdata.append('Weight', weight);
itemdata.append('Date', date);
itemdata.append('Color', color);
itemdata.append('Tag_Num2', itag2);
itemdata.append('Tag_Num3', itag3);
itemdata.append('User_Email', useremail);

  var isValid = false;
  $.ajax({           
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/AddNewItem.php",  
      data: itemdata,
      processData: false,
          contentType: false,
      success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
        if(resp.reply == "Success")
        {
          isValid = true;
          form.submit();
        }
        else
        {
       isValid = false;
        }
      },
      error: function(data, status){
        console.log(data, status);
        alert("error")
      }

    }); //end Ajax
    console.log(isValid);
     return isValid;
};
```

In my php file, I am retrieving image like this:

```
$itemmage = $_REQUEST["Item_Image"];
```

It is working if I don't select an image, so something is wrong with how I am getting my image or retrieving it.  Please help.

Comment: PHP has never provided the data of an actual file upload in $_REQUEST … http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_FILES` instead of `$_REQUEST`

### Edit

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['name']!=""){
    $image_name= $_FILES['image']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "images/$image_name");
}
```

`$_FILES` has an array for each image:

```
[name] => MyFile.jpg
[type] => image/jpeg
[tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
[error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
[size] => 98174
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: so I changed it to this $_FILES["Item_Image"];   still getting parse error.  is that syntax right?

Comment: PaddyHallihan - you are being very helpful.  Thank you.  So I don't want to move my file but I want to use a $sql = "INSERT INTO.   to insert into my database table.  So to what is proper syntax to move it into my database as a jpeg.  Right now it is upload and it is a .bin type.

Comment: Yeah so what I do is just get the file name and store that in my DB but if I want to display it on my site I'll need to upload/move it to the server or local environment so that I can reference the file location, for example I'd upload it to a `media/product_images/` directory, then store the name in my DB then I can call the name again and display it like `<img src='media/product_images/'.$file_name_from_db.''>`

Comment: If you don't upload/move it somewhere all you have is an array of info referencing an image that is still in the `tmp` folder of the computer that filled in the form and no actual image on the server/local environment

Comment: Paddy - Roger that.  I guess I have been going about it wrong. I thought I could directly upload a image to my database.  But I need to move the images to a directory in my site directory and just push the path to my database.  Is that right?

Comment: so mine are usually all in the same directory so i just store the name but you can upload them to different folders in some sort of conditional statement and then you could store the full file path of wherever you moved it to.

Comment: Paddy - I got it to work!!  Thank you so much.  Last question.  I will be having many different users so my image folder will get filled with a lot of different images.  Do you have any recommendations on keeping filenames unique.  Even the same user could upload an image with same name I would imagine.  I can only think to rename each image myself and keep some sort of global counter to add to the end of the image name.

Comment: So instead of saving the file name to the db you could get the last inserted id and use that as the var for the file name when you're uploading the file